# How to add Range value to string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm *saving as* my file and I'm currently using regular string name:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pleaseworkooo", FileFormat:=52
```

I have this **Range** value:

```
Dim mNumber As Range
Set mNumber = Range("C13:D13")
```

I want to save my file with the mNumber.Value, to save as the file with this value name.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: In windows?? A colon is not a valid sign in a filename on a windows machine.

Comment: If you still want to try go ahed with this: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pleaseworkooo" & mNumber, FileFormat:=52`

Comment: The range is two cells wide: in which one is stored the file name you need?

Comment: `mNumber.Value` will be an array of values, not a single value.  It would help if you show some sample data from C13:D13 and what the resulting filename should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("C13").Value
```

Even though the two cells C13 and D13 are merged, the "value" behaves as though it's in C13 (any value contained in a merged set of cells will be "in" the top-left cell)

If you try to get the Value from C13:D13 you still get an array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's my second user...
@Andreas - What do you mean by that?
@user - they are combined into one cell...
Tim - I have only one number, 207 for example...

This code is currently working:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pleaseworkooo", FileFormat:=52
```

Comment: C13:D13 is two cells, not one

Comment: I thought you wanted the filename to be "C13:D13.xlsx". @TimWilliams not always... If you merge them they are one large cell.

Comment: Also.. Why did you create an answer on a new username? why not comment or edit?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, as Andreas said, I merged them both into one big cell.

Comment: @Andreas The other user is one that I opened for extra questions (new in VBA haha) and I forgot the registration mail... Can you help me with my problem? :)

Comment: @Dave next time give more details in your post, it's hard to guess what you mean (or how you formatted your cells).

Comment: `Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("C13").Value`

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm quite sure that wont work. You need to refer to the full stretch of the cell, C13:D13

Comment: Ok... I will rephrase that. A friendly reminder: that will not always work.

Comment: @TimWilliams Works! Thanks you very much. Andreas - why would that won't always work? And if we change the Range to "Range("C13:D13")"?

Comment: If you use `Range("C13:D13")` it will fail, because the Value property of that range is a variant array, not a single value.

Comment: Don't know if it's because of version or how large the range is, but sometimes you need to use the full range. This worked on my computer, but I know I had massive problems with it on my workcomputer becuase I had no idea you had to use the full range.

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh right. If I write instead Range("D13"), would it be the same? How can we know?

Comment: @Andreas Oh.. btw, I can't comment on your answer but it wouldn't work... No idea why though, seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @Dave - C13 will work but D13 will give an empty value.

Comment: @TimWilliams Why's that?